# php in html page doesn't work

Tags: php, phpstorm-2016.3

I'm using PhpStorm 2016 with php language level 5.6 and the interpeter is PHP 5(5.6.24) and xampp version 3.2.2 .
I'm trying to add some php code in html page,
I created a file `.htaccess` in the same folder where my html file located, and put `AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm` inside it, added `<?php echo "example" ?>` but it doesn't show up.
I even tried `<FilesMatch "\.html$">
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>`, `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm` and `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm` but nothing work, don't know what eles to do.

Hope you can help me with any idea.

Thank you.

Comment: You may need to edit the Apache config file, and check if  `AllowOverride` is set to none. If AllowOverrideList is set to None, .htaccess files are completely ignored. See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Comment: It is none, so for what should I change it to instead?

Comment: To allow only the ForceType directive it would be "AllowOverride FileInfo"   or if you want all entries in your .htaccess to be honored, then "AllowOverride All"

Answer (score 1):

You may need to edit the Apache config file, and check if AllowOverride is set to none. If AllowOverride is set to None, .htaccess files are completely ignored.

See httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride

To allow only the ForceType directive it would be

```
AllowOverride FileInfo
```

or if you want all entries in your .htaccess to be honored, then

```
AllowOverride All
```

Comment: I don't have AllowOverrideList in apache config file at all, I tried to change AllowOverride from none to All, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

In order to get xampp to interpret the file as PHP, you will need to set the Apache Server web-root to the base of your project (where the html files are) and access the webserver via the server (HTTP in a web-browser).

It sounds like you're trying to access the file directly with the browser (skipping the PHP processor).

Comment: I can run php files seperatly but not inside html file